# How to find max values in a list of lists by corresponding indices using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to find the max of all index items in a list, which is the efficient way, Does numpy have any function or efficient and best pythonic way, my list elements will length above 100, with each list with 20 elements.

eg:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1,4,5,6],[4,3,2,1,5,6],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
max_list = [4,3,3,4,5,6]
```

My list will length to around 100, with each inner list with 20 elements

Comment: Not sure what your constraints are, but why not turn the list of lists into a numpy array and then take the max on whatever axis you prefer? (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

Comment: Alex Hall answer is very good. Too bad it's a duplicate (nice dupe find BTW)

Answer (score 9):

Solution without numpy:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1,4,5,6],[4,3,2,1,5,6],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
list(map(max, *data))
```

The `list` is not needed in Python 2 (or even in Python 3, depending on what you're going to do with the result)

Comment: you could explain the not so known fact that `map` can iterate on several lists at once.

Comment: There is a small issue. It will not work when `data` contains only one sublist or is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Also without numpy (but with help of comment authors)

```
inp = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1,4,5,6],[4,3,2,1,5,6],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
out = [max(s) for s in zip(*inp)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1,4,5,6],[4,3,2,1,5,6],[1,1,1,1,1,1]])
a.max(0) #a.max(axis=0)
```

Which results in:

```
array([4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```